# ubuntu 12.04 with windows 8 dual boot not booting

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I followed the procedure mentioned at [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) on toshiba satellite laptop.

also tried the boot-repair and logs @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/6327398/

Its not booting to windows as well as ubuntu. It goes to grub command prompt.

When on initial screen it briefly shows error message as failed to open /efi/Microsoft/boot/grubx64.

Please advise.

EDIT : Secure boot in on and boot mode is UEFI Boot

Comment: Do you have secure boot on? It does look like you have the signed kernels installed so it should boot with secure boot on or off. Not sure if shim gets renamed to grubx64, but you should be booting shim if in secure boot mode.

Comment: Bug 1091464 may prevent you from booting Windows from grub.  If so, use the efi menu to select harddisk then Windows.  My Toshiba S855 -5378 never needed to rename any bootloaders either.

Answer (score 0):

The error message refers to `/efi/Microsoft/Boot/grub64.efi` (I presume there was a `efi` after the dot there, although your message didn't say so.) This implies that shim is installed in `/efi/Microsoft/Boot`, presumably as `bootmgfw.efi`, and is being launched; however, your Boot Repair output shows no evidence of `grubx64.efi` being present there, as it must be. (Shim is hard-coded to launch `grubx64.efi` from the same directory in which it resides.)

This suggests an easy solution: Copy `grubx64.efi` from `/efi/ubuntu` to `/efi/Microsoft/boot`. You'll need to use an emergency disc and mount `/dev/sda2` somewhere convenient to do this copy, of course.